# distributing the akka micro kernel application with maven

Tags: java, maven, akka

I have an akka micro kernel application developed in java. 
 To distributed the application , I used the tutorials at the JCrankyi's blog

```
 http://jcranky.com/2012/07/13/akka-microkernel-with-maven/#comment-1322
```

using the maven-assembly-plugin and the the akka start script.

the descriptor.xml is presented below

```
 <id>akka</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${Com-RubineEngine-GesturePoints}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/deploy</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>

  <files>
    <file>
      <source>src/main/start</source>
      <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
    </file>

    <file>
      <source>src/main/resources/application.conf</source>
      <outputDirectory>/config</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>

</assembly>
```

The snippets from the POM.xml

```
 <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>/descriptor.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

the start file is a batch file and the content is presented below.

```
@echo off
set SAMPLE=%~dp0..
set AKKA_HOME=%SAMPLE%\..\..\..\..
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseParallelGC
set AKKA_CLASSPATH=%AKKA_HOME%\lib\scala-library.jar;%AKKA_HOME%\lib\akka\*
set SAMPLE_CLASSPATH=%SAMPLE%\config;%AKKA_CLASSPATH%;%SAMPLE%\lib\*

java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp "%SAMPLE_CLASSPATH%" -Dakka.home="%SAMPLE%" akka.kernel.Main
```

the error from the maven assembly:assembly plugin is presented below.

```
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: /descriptor.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.124s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 07 11:46:10 GMT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.
3:single (make-assembly) on project com-theta-gesture: Failed to create assembly
: Error adding file to archive: C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-theta-gestu
re\src\main\start isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Comment: Have you seem my updated version of the script here https://gist.github.com/3151127 ? Perhaps you are missing the <fileMode>744</fileMode> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is rather clear.

```
C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-theta-gesture\src\main\start isn't a file
```

I assume that `src/main/start` is a folder and you will have to specify the name of a file in that folder. At least it is not recognized as a file.

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source>src/main/start</source>
        <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files>
```

I think you should put the start script in `src/main/scripts` as described in the [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source>src/main/scripts/start.bat</source>
        <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
    </file>
</files>
```

---

**Edit**

In order to verify that your `start` file is really a file then just add a simple JUnit test to your `src/main/test` directory. Here is a simple example:

```java
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-11-08
 */
public class FileTest {
    @Test
    public void testIfStartScriptIsFile() {
        File file = new File("src/main/scripts/start.bat");
        assertTrue("The tested file is not a real file!!!", file.isFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Maba for the suggestions. But looks like maven is not able to recognise the script file even after trying your suggestions. Is there any possible workaround that comes to mind.

Comment: The `maven-assembly-plugin` is just using `plexus-archiver` to put files in the archive. I checked the sources and it uses [`java.io.File#isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile()) so you can run a simple test yourself with `isFile()` and verify. Do a simple unit test for example.

Comment: thanks , the simple file test helped me figure out what the problem was. Maven was not able to find the file . So I had to fix the location problem. thanks.