# Deploy Akka java microkernel with maven

Tags: maven, akka

I am trying my hands on JCranky's tutorials about distributing akka microkernel with maven and tbt start scripts [click](http://jcranky.com/2012/07/13/akka-microkernel-with-maven/#comment-1607). from the descriptor.xml file I suppose there are four directories to be created by the assembly pluggin.

below is the descriptor.xml file

```
<id>akka</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/deploy</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>

  <files>
    <file>
      <source>src/main/start</source>
      <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
    </file>

    <file>
      <source>src/main/resources/application.conf</source>
      <outputDirectory>/config</outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>

</assembly>
```

The following directories are created in the zip folder. that is the lib, config and bin directories. Reading from the descriptor.xml file , looks like the deploy directory has to be created. don't know if I am missing something. Will be very happy for a clarification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [distributing the akka micro kernel application with maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269293/distributing-the-akka-micro-kernel-application-with-maven)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong `directory` in the fileset.

Change to:

```
<directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
```

It cannot find any files in the place you stated. Thus no files were copied and the `deploy` directory didn't have to be created.

Comment: I have changed the product to project but it still does not create the deploy directory. I have also edited the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: I just ran that configuration and there's no problem with it. The `deploy` folder is created inside the zip file. In what phase are you running the assembly plugin? It must be run after all the jars has been created.

Comment: At first I run the assembly plugin without running the mvn package command. After running the mvn package command first and then running the assembly plugin the deploy package is created with the developed application as jar file in the deploy folder. I don't know if that is the right way to do it? Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: The 'mvn assembly:single' does just that, it assembles files according to the descriptor file. Nothing more nothing less. You can (and should) bind the plugin to the package phase. Then a simple 'mvn package' would do it all in one go.

Comment: so how do you bind the assembly plugin to the package phase. Will be very greatful for an explanation

Comment: You had a correct configuration in your previous akka question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269293/distributing-the-akka-micro-kernel-application-with-maven. There you bind the plugin to the `package` phase.

Comment: Thanks , was able to use the package phase to run the assembly:single goal